# how can i give a number from input and make a triangle in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

how can i Write a program that reads n from input and displays a pattern like the following output:

[pattern image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpWNh.png)

i just know the code that much:

```
row = int(input('Enter how many lines? '))
for i in range(1,row+1):

# increace
for j in range(1,i+1):
    print(j, end='')

#  decreasing  
for j in range(i-1,0,-1):
    print(j, end='')

# move to next
print()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not that far for the increasing part.
Then for the decreasing part, you can do the same but using a range from `row-1` to 0, using -1 as the third parameter which is the step. It means the range will be decreasing.

See below example using your first version.
This is a very raw answer that works and may help just for this exercise. However, as a second step you can try to create functions to avoid repeating the same code several times etc.
This looks like a very classical beginner's exercise so I'm sure you can find a lot of good solution online.

```
row = int(input('Enter how many lines? '))
print("*") # first empty line
for i in range(1,row+1):
    print("*", end='')
# increase
    for j in range(1,i+1):
        print(j, end='')

#  decreasing  
    for j in range(i-1,0,-1):
        print(j, end='')
    print("*")

# Decrease
for i in range(row-1, 0, -1): # row-1 to avoid repeating the longest row
    print("*", end='')

    for j in range(1,i+1):
        print(j, end='')

    for j in range(i-1,0,-1):
        print(j, end='')
    print("*")
print("*") # last empty line
```